# Do neural networks use efficient coding?

Tags: neural-networks, information-theory

My question concerns the relationship between the efficient coding hypothesis which is outlined on the [Wikipedia page on efficient coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient_coding_hypothesis) and neural network learning algorithms.

What is the relationship between the efficient coding hypothesis and neural networks?

Are there any neural network models explicitly inspired by the efficient coding hypothesis?

Or would it be fairer to say that all neural network learning algorithms are at least implicitly based on efficient coding?

Comment: Perhaps [sparse autoencoders](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bautoencoders%5d%20sparse) are what you are after? (If your interest is less technical and more broad/philosophical, user kenorb's suggestion may be appropriate.)

Comment: Interesting question. My guess is NNs are nowhere near what we may consider “efficient”. I think commonly used techniques such as Dropout would actually seek to decrease coding efficiency.

Comment: Another reference: The Lottery Ticket Hypothesis, https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.03635 the paper talks about finding the  hard working sub networks but I think there may be connections to efficient coding

Comment: I'm not an information theory expert, but I don't believe that there is any relationship between efficient coding what NNs do, nor am I aware of any historical or present attempts to incorporate efficient coding. However, it might be true that NNs do encode signals efficiently: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02406

Comment: I don't have enough (yet) to make this an answer, but this seems to me to relate to the question of whether NNs are really just memorizing, rather than learning.

Comment: For example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.07714.pdf

"Surprising empirical results by Zhang et al showed that DNNs are able to fit pure noise, establishing that the effective capacity of DNNs is sufficient for memorizing the entire data set, and raising the question whether memorization played a similar role in real datasets."

Answer (score 1):

I believe that one can argue that a connection has been made. I'll apologize for not posting my source as I couldn't find it, but this came from an old slide that Hinton presented. In it, he claimed that one of the fundamental ways of thinking for those who do machine learning (as the presentation predated the common use of the word deep learning) was that there exists an optimal transformation of the data such that the data can be easily learned. I believe for neural nets, the 'optimal transformation' of the data though back prop, IS the efficient coding hypothesis in action. In the same way that given a proper kernel, many spaces can be easily classified with linear models, learning the proper way to transform and store the data IS analogous to which and how the neurons should be arranged to represent the data.